# Convert sharepoint display name to SPUser

Tags: sharepoint

How to convert this display name to SPUser type: 
My input is :FirstName, SecondName (ext)(domain\user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string input = @":FirstName, SecondName (ext)(domain\user)";
var loginName = Regex.Match(input, @"\((?<login>[^\(\\]+\\[^\(\\]+)\)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture).Groups["login"].Value;
var user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);
```

Using [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var loginName = input.Split('(', ')')[3];
var user = web.EnsureUser(loginName);
```